# Python Gtk 3 window is not defined, class instancing confusion

Tags: python, gtk3

I am just starting to get into python and I am utterly confused as to how object creation works. I am trying to create user interface with GTK. Here is an example of the problem I am having:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk


def button_clicked(self, button):
    self.button_label = button.get_label()
    if self.button_label == "Login":
        window.quit()
        window2.start()

class LoginWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="AMOK Cloud")
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_position(position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

        # Button
        self.loginbutton = Gtk.Button(label="Login")
        self.loginbutton.connect("clicked", button_clicked(self, self.loginbutton))
        self.add(self.loginbutton)

        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def quit(self):
        self.close()
        Gtk.main_quit()

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="AMOK Cloud")
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_position(position=Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

    def start(self):
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

window = LoginWindow()
window2 = MainWindow()
```

Error comes up as NameError: name 'window' is not defined
even though I did define window. I don't understand. If someone can explain it would mean the world to me. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Thanks guys this works fine now, took Gtk.main() out of both classes and added button_clicked method inside LoginWindow() class and now it works like a charm. I assumed I needed Gtk.main() for every window I open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are starting the main loop (`Gtk.main()`) inside of `LoginWindow.__init__()`.  That means that the `window = LoginWindow()` line doesn't finish executing until after the login window is closed.  You should take `Gtk.main()` outside of the `__init__` method, and move it to the last line in the file.  As mentioned by PM 2Ring in the comments, you don't need to call `Gtk.main()` twice.  Take it out completely in `MainWindow.start()` because the one now added to the last line in the file takes care of that.  Also mentioned by PM, `connect()` calls a function when an event happens.  When you give it `button_clicked(...)`, that function is called and you are actually telling `connect()` to call whatever is returned, `None`.  If you want special arguments, use a `lambda`, but you aren't even changing anything (those are the default arguments anyway), so you can simply do this:

```
self.connect("clicked", button_clicked)
```

I would also suggest that instead of making `button_clicked` a separate function, make it a static method of the class.  You do that by placing it inside the class, but with `@staticmethod` just above the `def` line.  That way, it makes sense for it to take the `self` argument, but you don't need two parameters to account for the same window.

Comment: I don't have the Python stuff for GTK3 (I still use GTK2+), so I won't write an answer. But `Gtk.main()` also needs to be removed from `MainWindow.start`. Also, the callback to `self.loginbutton.connect` needs to be fixed: currently it's being assigned to the value returned by the `button_clicked` call, which is `None`. And I guess `button_clicked` really ought to be a method of `LoginWindow`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Actually, I don't have GTK3 either ;)  Thank you for your suggestions; I have edited.